# Get associated products

Tags: admin, magento-1.8

I created a new module to create a section in admin panel. This module section has a sub-section "Associated products" where I can add one or more products to each item in that module.

I am able to get the field values using functions like

- `$combo->getName()`
- `$combo->getComments()`

But I am not able to get the associated products to that item using

```
$combo->getAssociatedProducts()
```

What I tried is as follows:

```
<?php $comboCollection = Mage::getResourceSingleton('combo/combo_collection'); ?>
<?php 
    foreach ($comboCollection as $combo) {
        zend_debug::dump($combo->getAssociatedProducts($combo));  //giving error       
    }
?>
```

PS: here `$combo` is not a product, it is just an item in the created module.

**Explanation**:

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that you created your module with the [Ultimate Module Creator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html), here is how you can get the associated products of your entity.

```
$collection = $combo->getSelectedProductsCollection(); //get associated products
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name'); //add 'name' attribute to collection - you can add others
$collection->addUrlRewrite(); //add the url rewrite to the collection
$collection->getSelect()->order('related.position'); //sort by the position you filled in the admin panel
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection); //get only enabled products
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection); //get only visible products.
```

Comment: I tried this.. this is taking a while to load and then showing me a blank page. The tables which created are [combo_combo](http://i.imgur.com/TOhH0ZA.png) and [combo_combo_product](http://i.imgur.com/3dUEDUh.png). There is also another table which is not related to get the associated product collection i.e `combo_combo_store`.

Comment: I asked the same question on SO. where I got this reply.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20604751/1577396) (_not working_)

Comment: @Mr_Green. Enable the log and check var/log for errors.

Comment: Got it!! not sure what was the problem though. just refreshed the page :/

Comment: I added a image attribute.. I am trying to get url of the uploaded image. if I do `$combo->getImage()` I am getting suffix of the url but not complete url. I have seen that there is `_getImageUrl()` (_present in abstract class_) in Helper class but I am unable to use it.. I don't know how to use it.. tried different ways.. no use...

Comment: @Mr_Green. Try with `$imgUrl = (string)Mage::helper('combo/image')->init($combo, 'image')->resize(60,60)`. The `resize` is optional. Use it only if you need a specific size.

Comment: I am getting error: `Fatal error: Class 'Efk_Combo_Helper_Image' not found`.. I checked my directory there is no such class.. I have a path which is close to the above i.e `Efk_Combo_Helper_Image_Abstract`.. I tried with this.. I am getting error: `Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Efk_Combo_Helper_Image_Abstract`.

Comment: @Mr_Green See my answer on e-mail. No need to involve all people on this website.